# apache solr search sorting by field value

Tags: solr

I'm using Apache solr search and having problem in sorting by field value.

Can any one resolve this issue?

i.e Suppose we have a field named 'function_area' and value may be 1,2,3,4.

But I want that record containing function_area=2 should come on top and the rest records should come in ascending order by function_area.

Records in order

**Record 1 => function_area=2**

**Record 2 => function_area=1**

**Record 2 => function_area=3**

**Record 2 => function_area=4**

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of sort parameters which are present as [CommonQueryParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) in Solr. Moreover, [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function) since Solr 3.1 can also be explored here.

The `exists` function may be used in order to get the results with specific field value ordered first:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select=q=*:*&sort=exists(query({!v='function_area:2'})) DESC
```

Comment: I am not getting the expected result actually i want function_area having value 2 should display on top and rest function_area having value 1,3,4 come in ascending order.

Records in solor in this order
 
Slno. 1 Record contains function_area 1

Slno. 2 Record contains function_area 2

Slno. 3 Record contains function_area 3

Slno. 4 Record contains function_area 4


but i want record in this order


Slno. 2
Slno. 1
Slno. 3
Slno. 4

it means Slno. 2 record should come on top

Comment: @user3386503 Updated answer with more specific example.